# nodm not working on bootup

Tags: ubuntu, display-manager

I've setup and used `nodm` in the past (it is extremly simple and easy), but now cannot get it working. My base system is Ubuntu 13.04 server, but I have tried Debian and older Ubuntu servers as well.

What I get is my system launching into a TTY, and every 60 seconds my screen flickering like `nodm` is trying to startup. If I manually launc it (`sudo nodm`) it starts and works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. My `.xession` file needed execution permission (700). I don't get why this was working if I ran `nodm` manually, but it works now.

Comment: This worked for me, too, on 14.04. It'd be nice to know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Also, problem may be in misconfigured `x11-common`.

Run `dpkg-reconfigure x11-common` and select `Anybody` option.